# Discrete time equivalent to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a paper in which it is noted that
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = f(t) - \varepsilon v(t)$$
has the discrete time equivalent
$$v(t+1) = v(t)\exp(-\varepsilon) + \frac{f(t)}{\varepsilon}[1 - \exp(-\varepsilon)].$$

How is this derived?

**Update:**
In case I have misunderstood, my question is a simplified version of the text appearing at the top of Page 2 in [this supplementary material](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v511/n7508/extref/nature13529-s1.pdf) from [this paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v511/n7508/abs/nature13529.html).  Namely
$$\frac{dv_i}{dt}=\frac{I_i}{N_i} - \varepsilon v_i$$
$$v_i(t+1)=v_i(t)\exp(-\varepsilon)+\frac{I_i}{\varepsilon N_i}[1-\exp(-\varepsilon)]$$
Where I understand $\tfrac{I_i}{N_i}$ to be the evolving proportion of infectious animals at a location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discretization comes from the solution to the full first-order ODE. You have

$$ v' + \epsilon v = f$$

Using an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor), the general solution to this has the form

$$ v(t) = e^{-\epsilon t} \left( v(0) + \int_0^{t} e^{\epsilon \tau} f(\tau) \, d\tau \right) $$

For small time, we might approximate $f$ as a constant, in which case the above solution becomes

$$ v(t) \approx e^{-\epsilon t} v(0) + \frac{f(0)}{\epsilon} \left(1 - e^{-\epsilon t} \right) $$

Your discretization is a time shift of the above.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting $ v(t) $ from either side gives:
$$
v(t+1) - v(t) = v(t) \exp(-\epsilon) - v(t) + \frac{f(t)}{\epsilon}( 1 - \exp(- \epsilon ) )
$$
As $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 $, taylor expanding the exponentials, $ \exp(-\epsilon) = 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon^2 / 2 \cdots $, gives:
$$
v(t+1) - v(t) = -\epsilon v(t) + f(t) −{f(t)\epsilon \over 2} + O(\epsilon^2)
$$
then, to get to the desired equation we would have to neglect $\epsilon \over 2$ but leave $\epsilon$. I'm not entirely sure this is correct, or why it should be like this. But it would then yield:
$$
v(t+1) - v(t) = -\epsilon v(t) + f(t) + O\left({\epsilon \over 2} \right)
$$

The term $ v(t+1) - v(t) $ is discrete derivative, i.e. think of the difference quotient from first year calculus with $ h = \Delta t = (t+1)-t = 1 $.

Thus, 
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = -\epsilon v(t) + f(t)
$$

Comment: Did you make a small error? I get $v(t+1)=v(t)(1-\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)) + \frac{f(t)}{\varepsilon} ( 1-(1-\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2/2+O(\varepsilon^3)))=v(t)-\varepsilon v(t) + f(t) - \frac{f(t) \varepsilon}{2} + O(\varepsilon^2)$ (assuming $v$ and $f$ are both bounded).

Comment: If I've understood correctly, I think $\varepsilon$ is actually supposed to be a constant, so am unclear on whether an argument which is asymptotic in $\varepsilon$ is ok.

Comment: @freelang, you can argue that $\epsilon$ is very small by making a change of variable so that $v(t)$ gets most of its absolute value. That assumption is important so to make the discrete equation as precise as needed.